# Only open and read files of a directory inside of a directory

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, glob, os.path

Here is my new code. For some reason it is giving the error provided below. DOes anyone know why that may be? Or any method I could use to work around this problem?

New Code:

```
import glob
import re

folder_path = "/home/"
file_pattern = "/**/*"
folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern, recursive=True)

#Search for Emails
regex1= re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')
#Search for Phone Numbers
regex2 = re.compile(r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d')

match_list=[]

for file in folder_contents:
    read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()
    if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file):

        email = regex1.findall(read_file)
        phone=regex2.findall(read_file)

        match_list.append(file)
        print (file)
        print (email)
```

Below is the error I receive:

```
/home//sample.txt
['bcbs@aol.com', 'James@aol.com']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-6281ab1fc0ff> in <module>()
     15 
     16 for file in folder_contents:
---> 17     read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()
     18     if regex1.findall(read_file) or regex2.findall(read_file):
     19 

/jupyterhub_env/lib/python3.5/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Do I need to add an if else statement to specify the file type or..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You can glob subdirectories with wildcards and recursive True: `glob.glob(path + '/**/*', recursive=True)`

Comment: Different kinds of file may have different way to read, for example zip cannot be read as text, but read as binary is right. (it is same to pdf, jupyter, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The `glob` module allows this by specifying `recursive=True`:

```
folder_path = "/home/e136320"
file_pattern = "/**/*"
folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern, recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is clearly not in the locale encoding Python is detecting. Your locale is looking for UTF-8 data, but it looks like the file is in some other encoding. Assuming you mostly work on English locales, a couple good guesses would be `cp1252` and `latin-1`; try passing `encoding='cp1252'` to the `open` call and see if it works. `latin-1` will never fail, but it may produce gibberish, while Windows machines frequently produce `cp1252` data, making it a good guess.